# Joining two tables to get exact matches

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have one table with 1000 records and one with 999. table structure looks like this....

tbl1

```
 RecNo             ClietID         FName          LName
 1                 177             bob            doe
```

tbl2

```
 recNo2            ClientID          fName       Lname
 1                 177               bob         doe
```

The structure is very similar, one is the main table for all clients, while the other is a table for all DELeted clients. I'm trying to join both tables, so it shows me the records in tbl1 that are currently not in tbl2....Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to find records in either table not in the other?  what are the keys of such tables? clientID? recNo?

Comment: @xQbert yes, so in this case show me the 1 record from tbl1 (where there are 1000 records) that does not have the exact CLIENT ID match in tbl2 (where there are 999 records).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative option; if you know that `Tab1` always has more records than `Tab2` and their column/data structures are identical, and you are using *all* columns to indicate uniqueness, you could also do the following:

```
Select * From Tab1
Except
Select * From Tab2
```

Comment: Yeah tbl2 has more columns but good to know, i can simplay manually add them. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Return all records from either table which don't exist in the other.
assuming clientID and recNo define a unique record.
Using a full outer join with a null check on the key should work

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM tbl1 A
FULL OUTER JOIN tbl2 B
 on A.RecNo = b.RecNo
and A.ClientID = B.ClientId
WHERE (A.ClientID is null and A.RecNo is null)
  or (B.ClientID is null and B.RecNo is null)
```

If we knew for a fact tab2 had fewer records and thus we wanted to check existence of a delete for a record in tab1 we could use a not exists ...

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM tab2 B
                  WHERE A.ClientID = B.ClientID 
                    and A.RecNo= B.recNO)
```

Comment: That did it, thank you - 2nd will suffice - I'm doing some testing - so i know for a fact that tbl2 has a few fewer records than tbl1.

Comment: Just missed alias for `tab2` and  second parentheses in `NOT EXISTS` query